# Xcode Bots Server Continuous Integration Failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, osx-server

I'm getting this error when trying to use an Xcode bot to integrate for unit tests:

`Integration failed. Unexpected error while building. See the integration's logs for more details.`

I couldn't make any sense of the logs.  They pretty much spit out any error with the system whether related or not.

I use a remote repository from from Github, testing currently on only 1 device.  I'm .gitignore-ing the standard stuff from Xcode.

Here is the most relevant messages from the log I could find:

`'2014-01-01 10:03:04.195 xcodebuild[19150:100b] Error opening /var/teamsserver/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/iOS Simulator.log'`

`Symbols directory specified does not exist at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Resources/sync_ddi line 17.`

`xcodebuild: error: No destinations were specified with the -destination flag which were valid for the specified scheme 'MyTestsScheme'.`

The last one reported was the third one.  Seems to be the most directly related too.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever tried configuring Aggregate target which contains only Run Script within it? I have configured Aggregate target with shared scheme on OS X Server but that does produces same error as you have described. I tried below answers but none got succeeded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue was caused because my Scheme was configured for Testing only.  I fixed the issue by going to Edit Scheme, selecting "Run", then switching the Executable from 'none' to my .app file.

Comment: In my case, I have configured the Aggregate target as Bot on OS X Server, which itself does not have any Executable app file. So, this solution is not working in my case. Can you help me??

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason to see this error is that you are running the test on "All Devices" yet you have no compatible devices plugged in for testing on (such as an iOS 7.1 device, or an iPad).

Answer (score 0):

the -destination flag seems like it corresponds to a particular device

Try setting some custom xcodebuild arguments in the scheme with something like:

```
test -destination OS=7.0.4,name=iPhone
```

Also from what I've read in the past, there seems to be a lot of mention of the scheme being checked into git repo... if you have a scout around on google, you'll see there's a handful of posts about this around the web.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem.
But your solution did not work for me.
I got it around by checking off the 'Parallelize Build' option in 'Build' item of the schema.